# iPhone X unable to connect to cell network after being in basement

Tags: iphone, network

iPhone X, Model MQAG2QN/A, Verizon

I work from home in the basement, where I have a poor or non-existent cell phone signal. The iPhone shows 4 gray dots near the WiFi icon, and 'No Service' in the Control Center:

[image: Home screen]

[image: Control Center]

This is expected and unsurprising - however, when I go back upstairs or outside, the phone often **continues** to show the "No Service" and does not connect to the cellular network. If I restart the phone, it connects and operates as usual.

I'd like to avoid needing to constantly restart my phone. Unsuccessful steps taken so far:

- Made sure I am on the latest iOS version (13.3.1 at the time of this writing).
- Checked for a Carrier Settings update from Settings > General > About.
- Reset network settings from Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings.
- Turned the cell connection on/off from the Control Center.
- Turned Airplane Mode on/off from the Control Center.
- Turned Cellular Data off/on from Settings > Cellular.

A potentially unusual aspect is that I have an EU model phone on a US network (Verizon).

Comment: Try settings > cellular > Cellular data options > enable 4g and turn it off and on

Comment: @ankii No luck, I'll add this to the post too.

Comment: Have you tried toggling Airplane Mode on then off again?  It's the same thing as restarting the cellular, WiFi and Bluetooth without restarting the whole phone.

Comment: Also, could you post a screen shot?  When we have no service here in the US, we get the actual words "No Service" and not 4 dots.  See:  https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT207354

Comment: @Allan Yes, I tried Airplane mode. I added screenshots to the post. The home screen doesn't show "No Service" but it does in the Control Center.

Comment: It did say "No Service" which is key...I was actually in a hospital today and one of the interior rooms was so far in, I lost signal for about 3 hours.  I got the No Service indicator, but the phone came right back up without needing to reboot.  It's entirely possible it's because yours is an EU model, but without actually having one to test I can't do much more than give you anecdotal evidence.  You might want to give Apple a call and see what they say.